# how to get all media files from folder with sub folders in server using php

Tags: php

I have get the media files from server folder. The server folder contains multiple sub folder and each sub folder contains some media files. I need get the all media files from each folders. how can i get it..

Comment: 'grab' is not very descriptive so it is hard to tell what it is you really want to do, but you have 2 options grep, or recursion; each have benefits and drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Read about PHP's [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php).

you can look down on user-comments, there are a few functions there you can use.